# multiple parameters for stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql, t-sql, parameters, procedure

I need to select 45 fields from a record which has 96 of them (dont ask me, but i can't normalize them, i would if i could). So, I have this page who would need all those 45 on them once it's loaded in front of the user.

Basically, I was thinking, I would make a new stored proc that would retrieve all the fieldnames and put them into one field and all the values and put them into another field and basically would end up with two parameters. I would then end up processing them in C#.

Now my question is, 1, is it the right way to do it? 2nd, if it is I can't figure out how to select the fields and put it on one parameter.

```
select @sql = ' select 'field1' + 'field2' + 'field3'.....
```

im confused on where to start?

Comment: whats wrong with just using a normal select field1, field2, ... from table1 ? don't make it more complex than it is, especially if there is no good reason

Comment: It might just be me, but shouldn't stored procedures be avoided whenever possible? Also why not simply select those columns you need? And as a sidenote, depending on what your UI looks like and what freedom you have, maybe you could reorganize it in order to limit the total amount of information displayed at once (I don't really like seeing complex UIs)

Comment: @dSebastien - stored procedures should be used when appropriate. Why would they exist otherwise?

Comment: Is it always the same 45 fields or does the user get to choose which 45 to use?

Comment: @Oded I guess it's one of my 'religious' choices. I tend to agree with most of what Jeff Atwood pointed out about stored procedures: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/10/who-needs-stored-procedures-anyways.html . Having written way too many PL/SQL stored procedures (for a temporary work on an Oracle ERP implementation), I've felt the pain and it must've turned in some kind of unreasonable hatred, but I agree that there are (rare?) circumstances where they can be useful.

Comment: Stored procedures can be useful if your company has a DBA in charge of maintaining the entire database. He chooses what functions to expose to the developers. There have been much debate but there is no difference in performance if you use stored procs or you don't. So I think it's just a personal preference and what works best for your company. I disagree with Jeff Atwood. Yes, for small projects they are cumbersome and pointless. But for large projects they encourage you to use the data you've been given more efficiently, than to make another tiny query.

Comment: Well spoken. A good defense of an anti-pattern. Sadly you fall to the same arguments most sp defentders do, and those area fallacy. Look up Frans Bourma's stored procedure blog post via google. It pretty much kills your arguments as it should. Wasted money is not a personal preference, as it inefficient cumbersome code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well for one thing you are making this way more complex than it needs to be. How in the world you have 96 columns on one table I will never know, but to select the 45 you need you're just going to have to type out 45 columns in the select statement.

Here is a sample of what the SQL would look like. Naturally I'm not going to type 45 columns, but you get the idea:

```
SELECT FirstName, LastName, Age, [keep going to 45] FROM tblUsers
```

The other issue I would like to address is the way you are executing your SQL statement. NEVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER EVER concatenate string variables into one SQL string. Make sure you are using parameterized queries at the very least. But I would recommend looking into Entity Framework or LINQ to SQL sometime as well.

```
SqlCommand scomm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName='" + firstName + "' WHERE UserID='" + userId + "'");
```

That ^^^ equals very bad. Think about what would happen if a user decided to be sneaky and make his first name `Harry' AND Admin='true`. You might think, "Oh, well I'll just do `firstName = firstName.Replace("'","''");` on all my variables. If you do that I will personally come punch you. Parameterize your queries like this:

```
SqlCommand scomm = new SqlCommand("UPDATE tblUsers SET FirstName=@FirstName WHERE UserID=@UserID");
scomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("FirstName", firstName));
scomm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("UserID", userId));
```

That ^^^ equals much better.

**EDIT** Also if you ever get a chance to re-work that monster of a table you have, try refactoring subsets of fields into their own entity (table) and linking them via a reference ID. For example, say I have a table called [tlbUsers] and it contains info about a specific user. Like this:

```
[tlbUsers]
UserID
FirstName
LastName
Age
Username
StreetAddress
City
State
ZipCode
Country
Phone
```

Consider refactoring that so that related values have their own table. You could take all the address info from this users table and put it in a table called tlbAddresses. Not only would that make it easier to deal with when pulling in the data, but it could potentially save you space in the database. For instance, if Harry and Sally both live in the same home, they could reference the same address record.

```
[tlbUsers]
FirstName
LastName
Age
Username
AddressID
Phone

[tlbAddresses]
AddressID
Street
City
State
ZipCode
Country
```

Comment: so yeah, i know how to make the sql. what i was asking is if instead of writing the 45 columns i just try to loop around the fields and concatenate it just so i can insert it into a field and the values into another field and use that as output of my sp. and i would LOOOOVEEE to normalize this table so bad! I just can't right now.

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately I think this beast is gonna have to be dealt with by typing a lot in your queries. Anything else is just overkill. It would just be easier to refactor the tables in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

I am having a little trouble understanding your question, however if you want to pass a variable number of parameters to a stored procedure there are two ways I can think of that you can do it, which require SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 respectively.

The first leverages XML.  Have your procedure take a varchar(max) argument and then you can easily split it out.  For example, if you comma separate what you want, you could:

```
DECLARE @xml xml
SET @xml = cast('<x>'+replace(@yourArg,',','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml)

SELECT N.value('.','varchar(max)') AS myArgName FROM @xml.nodes('x') AS T(N)
```

Also, you could leverage table valued variables and select your inputs into a table and pass that to the stored procedure.  See http://www.sqlteam.com/article/sql-server-2008-table-valued-parameters for an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can return the data as xml in one field.

Test table

```
create table TestTbl(ID int, F1 int, F2 int, F3 int, F4 int) -- to F96
```

Test data

```
insert into TestTbl values (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
```

Query

```
select
  (select
    F1, F2, F3, F4 -- to F45 
   from TestTbl
   where ID = 1
   for xml path('root'), type) as XMLData
```

Result

```
XMLData
-----------------------------------------------------
<root><F1>2</F1><F2>3</F2><F3>4</F3><F4>5</F4></root>
```

XML in XMLData field

```
<root>
  <F1>2</F1>
  <F2>3</F2>
  <F3>4</F3>
  <F4>5</F4>
</root>
```